# In Lucifer can you perfect skills whilst stuck in a hell time loop?

Tags: lucifer-2016

In the *Lucifer* TV show it has been shown that time in hell is not the same as time on Earth and thousands of years in hell could just be a few weeks or months on Earth.

Some scenes have shown that people/souls are aware of the (hell) time in their time loop.

Now, the hell loop keeps repeating (since it is a loop!) and some people are doing a sport or playing a game e.g.

> Dan playing ping pong for thousands of years

Assuming that being bad at the game isn't the primary reason for their hell loop, would doing the same task repetitively be like training and they get better at the game over time, or is it just their mind that is conscious of time and their body/skills reset at the start of each loop?

Comment: The Lucifer TV show isn't related (except in terms of the character rights and a little bit of the back-story) to the Lucifer Vertigo comics.

Comment: I am just imagining a Sisyphus who says to himself, "Stone the crows,  I am really getting good at pushing rocks". Does not sound like any hell I ever heard of.

Comment: In Dan's case, his opponent was notably bad - the demon playing him was likely instructed to be bad at it - so while Dan may have improved his grip and whatnot over time, he probably would have gotten diminishing returns after a while, without better opponents to learn from.

Comment: FYI: The reason for the vertigo-comics tag was because the lucifer-2016 tag said to use it https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucifer-2016

Answer (score 2):

There's something that you have misread here. Playing Ping Pong was *not* Dan's hell loop; it was something else. But Lucifer intervened and created a special loop for Dan (i.e.: Playing infinite Ping Pong) instead of traditional torture.

Even if it was not directly implied, and under the condition that the soul is aware that they're stuck in a loop, the answer to your question is likely a **Yes**.
The most convincing evidence is [Lee Garner](https://lucifer.fandom.com/wiki/Lee_Garner) (or Mr. Said Out Bitch) breaking his hell loop and ascending to heaven by his determination to confront his guilt.    Which means that souls in hell can change for the better, and that includes their skills.
Another example would be that in the series finale,

> Lucifer is shown consulting therapies for the souls stuck in hell, hoping them to make them free of their guilt and let them ascend to heaven.